# How to use an ArrayList<String> as a parameter in a constructor in java?

Tags: java, string, arraylist, constructor

I have researched this, and have have found no simple (Straight to the point explanation).

I would really appreciate if anyone could explain (simply) how I would be able to use an ArrayList as a parameter for a constructor.

For example, (this is not actual code I am working on, I try to give a separate example so I can get a better understanding)

```
public class Shopping
{
//Instance of the variables
 private double money;
 private ArrayList<String> items;

 //Constructor
 public Shopping(double price, ArrayList<String> Item??){
      money = price;

      //Unsure as to what to put here for the ArrayList
      //Would it just be?
      items = Item;

      //Or would I put String Item as the parameter instead of the ArrayList....
    }
}
```

There is no main method in this class. As unit tests will be carried out. There will be a method to add items to the shopping list.

I apologise my previous explanation was not so clear. But basically, if I have ArrayList as a parameter in the constructor..

How would I call the constructor in the test case?

Comment: An `ArrayList<T>` is used the same way any other parameter is used. Instead of giving example code, actually try it out yourself. Make this compile and run it, see what happens.

Comment: Aside from the `??`, your code should compile and work as expected. If you still get problems, could you be more specific?

Comment: For example Shopping shop = new Shopping (0.75, this is not valid >>>"banana") so I would not know what to place here instead

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code would work, but the down-side to storing the same `ArrayList` instance that was passed to the constructor in your `Shopping` instance is that any changes done to this `ArrayList` after the constructor call would be reflected in the `Shopping` instance. You should consider storing a copy of the `ArrayList` in your class :

```
 public Shopping(double price, ArrayList<String> items)
 {
      money = price;  
      this.items = new ArrayList<String>(items);
 }
```

Comment: how would I create the instance for it? e.g for the String parameter constructor, it would be Shopping(2.3, "banana");
but for an arraylist it must differ?

Comment: @cardboard12I don't understand the question. Are you asking how you would call the constructor? `List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(); list.add("something"); Shopping shopping = new Shopping(2.3,list);`

Comment: Thanks, but I get an error.
actual argument List<String> cannot be converted to ArrayList<String> byt method invocation conversion.. This is what confuses me. I don't understand how I can create a contructor with One item (string) or more than one (arrayList).. and how would I pass these through to a constructor without receiving errors

Comment: @cardboard12 I still don't understand the problem. Can you post the code that causes you problems in your question?

Answer (score 0):

Passing an `ArrayList<String>` to a method has no differences with any other parameter.

```
public class Shopping {

    private double money;

    // I myself always instantiate any list to avoid NullPointerExceptions
    private ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();

    /**
     * Use this constructor to add multiple items to the 'items' list.
     */
    public Shopping(double price, ArrayList<String> itemsToAdd) {
        this.money = price;

        // If you want to add multiple items, you can just reassign
        // the 'items' property
        this.items = itemsToAdd;

        // Or you can just add all elements of 'itemsToAdd' to the
        // 'items' property using the 'addAll()' method.
        this.items.addAll(itemsToAdd);
    }

    /**
     * Use this constructor if you want a single element to be added
     * to the 'items' list.
     */
    public Shopping(double price, String itemToAdd) {
        this.money = price;

        // The ArrayList class inherits the method 'add()', which
        // allows you to add an element to the list.
        this.items.add(itemToAdd);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i often write this

```
public class Shopping {

private double money;
private ArrayList<String> items = null;

//Default constructor
public Shopping(){}
public Shopping(double price, ArrayList<String> itemsToAdd) {
    this.money = price;
    this.items=itemsToAdd;
}
```